# Switching two elements in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Is there a way to switch two elements in a linked list without removing and reinserting them? The code I am currently using is:

```
void exchange(int i, int j) {
    int[] temp = matrix.get(i);
    matrix.remove(i);
    matrix.add(i, matrix.get(j - 1));
    matrix.remove(j);
    matrix.add(j, temp);
}
```

where `matrix` is my linked list.

Comment: In Java, LinkedList is a bad choice if you intent to access the elements by index.  Consider ArrayList or Vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *must* implement it yourself, this will work:

```
void exchange(int i, int j) {
    ListIterator<int[]> it1 = matrix.listIterator(i),
                        it2 = matrix.listIterator(j);
    int[] temp = it1.next();
    it1.set(it2.next());
    it2.set(temp);
}
```

as will this:

```
void exchange(int i, int j) {
    matrix.set(i, matrix.set(j, matrix.get(i)));
}
```

The second is similar to how `Collections.swap` is implemented.  The first is slightly more efficient for a long linked list.

Answer (score 5):

Use the swap method in the Collections object: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: How do I go about implementing that?

Comment: Collections.swap(matrix, i, j)

Comment: Unfortunately, `Collections#swap()` is 2x *O(n)* for a linked list. See `LinkedList#entry(int)`, as used by `LinkedList#set(int, T)`. That's sad.

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix.set(i, matrix.set(j, matrix.get(i)));
```